# XPath query for list of UML class attributes that are not associations

Tags: xpath, uml, xmi, rational-rsa

I have a UML model developed with Rational Software Architect v9.1.2. I'm crafting a BIRT report with which I would like to show all of the class attributes that are NOT associations. I have the following XPath query:

```
resolveURI($classURI)/ownedAttribute[not(@association)]
```

This query returns all (2) of the attributes on the sample class *EmailAddress*, screen shot and xmi model fragment attached.

[image: Diagram Fragment]

[image: Model XMI fragment]

It seems that the association attribute is not recognized. This might be a namespace issue, but I'm not sure. Can anyone offer help?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd try is changing the qualifier to check for nullness - e.g.

resolveURI($classURI)/ownedAttribute[@association = null]

Never know.. might work! :)

cheers
Steve

Comment: Good suggestion. I tried it and the query returns zero rows as a result though. Darn!